# How to scan Wifi access point on Windows Mobile?

Tags: windows, wifi, windows-mobile, network-scan

I need to scan Wifi access point on Windows Mobile and connect the one of scanned results.
Currently I am using C# language, Windows Mobile 6.5 device, also to scan I am using the below code.

```
[DllImport(wlanapi.dll", SetLastError=true)]
```

I am using `wlanapi.dll`, but it seems that not possible to use on Mobile.

Does anyone know about the belows.

1. Could I use the dll in Windows Mobile 6.5 to scan and connect?
2. If the 1 is not possible, please let me know the different methods..

Please give me the clues.

Comment: CShop `=>` C#? (http://www.google.com/search?q=cshop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wlanapi.dll doesn't exist in WinMo/WinCE.  You have to use an API that is supported.

Most WinMo WiFi drivers (though probably not all) support the Wireless Zero Config (WZC) set of APIs.  The native versions of these APIs, like WZCQueryInterface, are [outlined in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa448301.aspx).

Microsoft does not provide any managed interface for these APIs, in fact the native documentation for them is pretty bad too.  The definitive "example" of it's use is in the NETUI component source of Platform Builder.  Gettign the eval version just for the source is very worthwhile if you plan to do much WinCE/WinMo development.

From a managed perspective I wrote an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446491.aspx) back in '06 that talks about using the SDF for getting network info.  The SDF has been reworked a lot since then, especially in the WZC area, but it's still pretty similar.

I did an [updated blog post](http://blog.opennetcf.com/2007/05/16/sdf-sample-custom-drawing-a-list-and-viewing-all-network-adapters-too/) in '07 about custom-drawn ListBoxes, and while that's not what you're after, the data being displayed is wireless network info, which is in line with what you're after.