# Wifi scan in WinMo 6.5

Tags: wifi, windows-mobile-6.5

New to posting here, so please forgive if my question is kinda basic.

I'm trying to find a way to scan for all available wifi access points on a WinMo6.5 device. I need get every individual access point (by MAC address) and its signal strength, not just a list of available SSIDs. I thought I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865897/how-to-scan-wifi-access-point-on-windows-mobile), but the link posted in the answer is dead. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be best to comment on that existing Answer requesting an updated link instead of asking another question...

Comment: I apparently don't have enough reputation to comment, so I guess I'll have to put my comment as an "Answer"

Comment: The link is available as http://web.archive.org/web/20081210125333/http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/CommentView,guid,418e2e48-09f7-4b10-a57e-a5e32b70b4b9.aspx, but the download is not. So you have to create your own scanner using OpenNetCF.net